# Disable Http Access on BitBucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

So I am trying to disable Http Access to my repository. This is what Bitbucket states on their [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/disabling-http-s-access-to-git-repositories-in-bitbucket-server-776640365.html)

> Disabling HTTP(S) access To disable HTTP(S) access: Go to the
>   Bitbucket Server administration area and click Server settings (under
>   'Settings'). Under 'HTTP(S) access', uncheck HTTP(S) enabled. Click
>   Save.

Now I cannot find the "Server Settings" on my main page. I tried clicking on the "Bitbucket settings" option when you click on the avatar however I do not see Server Settings anywhere. Any suggestions regarding this would be appreciated. I tried positing this in Atlassian Answers but the site keeps timing out.

Here is the image from my settings page
[image]

Comment: Are you sure go to the **Bitbucket Server administration**?

Comment: @vanloc How do I go to the BitBucket Server administration ? I dont see any option ? I just pasted my screenshot.

Comment: I tested on my computer. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bitbucket Server administration** is software provide by Atlassian.

You should download and install at bellow link:

https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/download

I was setup on my computer and go to the setting page. You can see like this:

[image]

Comment: Bitbucket Server is a separate, self-hosted product. It is _not_ used for interacting with a bitbucket.org account.

Answer (score 5):

Bitbucket Server (self-hosted) and Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org) have slightly different features. If you're using Bitbucket Cloud, which it sounds like you are, it is not currently possible to disable HTTPS access.

For more details, see: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/3775/add-the-option-to-disable-https-access-to